# Where to find the startup code in IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM project?

Tags: arm, iar

I am currently developing a makefile that uses IAR toolchain for ARM to build a project on an eclipse based IDE. I have successfully compiled all source files but in order to link the object files, I need to have the startup code for IAR. I can't seem to find where it is in any sample IAR projects using IAR IDE or eclipse with IAR plugin.

my target is: s32k144

Answer (score 1):

There is a GettingStarted project for s32k144 that can be downloaded from inside the IAR ide. In the directory for this project there is a sub-directory called `Startup` and in this directory there is a specialized `cstartup.s` file and a `low_level_init.c` file. In addition to this, the `config` sub-directory contains a linker configuration file for this chip. For some reason this linker configuration places the code in ram and not in flash but that is probably easy to fix.